# sed to replace string with . and replace string have . too

Tags: shell-script, sed

I have  myfile.conf with this content:

```
ServerAlias *.mysite.com
```

I'm trying to convert to:

```
ServerAlias *.xxmysite.com
```

but I get:

```
ServerAlias *.xx.mobilsem.com

areemplazar="ServerAlias *."
reemplazo="ServerAlias *.xx"
sed -i ''  -- "s|${areemplazar}|${reemplazo}|g"  ./myfile.conf
```

When I use escape points like "ServerAlias *." , there is no reeplace.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Period `.` and asterisk `*` as regex metacharacters should be escaped to treat them literally:

Sample input file:

```
$ cat input.txt
ServerAlias *.mysite.com
```

---

```
sed 's/ServerAlias \*\./&xx/' input.txt
ServerAlias *.xxmysite.com
```